# Securely wipe data so it could not be restored

Tags: lumia

I wanted to use ccleaner driver wiper, but smartphone device is not listed as drive. I want to overwrite phone memory so it could not be restored.

Comment: Restored by who? A consumer, or a state intelligence service, or somewhere in between?

Comment: Anyone with proper recovery tools can restore data on simply erased/formatted drive. I want something more secure.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to wipe it the way you think.

The drive is [BitLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831713.aspx) encrypted so it can not be read by any device other than the phone itself. The phone itself is so secure that no app can read from the drive at the level that's needed to find erased data.

**Simply reset the phone to factory settings and you're good to go.**

Comment: Note that on Windows Phone 8.x there's no way to manually enable BitLocker, and *it's not enabled by default*! See http://superuser.com/questions/549515/how-can-i-turn-on-bitlocker-encryption-on-windows-phone-8. In Windows 10 Mobile, you can manually enable BitLocker ("Settings" -> "Update & security" -> "Device encryption").

Comment: It can be enabled for WP8 devices managed by a company.